# Determine OS in which the TeX compilation is taking place

Tags: compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print ‘system information’ in LaTeX doc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78334/print-system-information-in-latex-doc)

Is there any way to determine whether the TeX document is compiling in Windows, Linux or Mac OS?